# Markov Chains- transition matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, transition-matrix, stochastic-matrices

> [image]

Ok so whilst I was reading my notes on Markov chains, this is a particular part in the notes I don't completely understand. I don't get how its clear from (1.17) that rows of U are the normalized left eigenvectors for P, simiarly how the columns of U inverse are the normalized right eigenvectors of P. Lastly, where P here is a transition matrix, could someone explain why a transition matrix must have an eigenvalue of 1 always?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've  diagonalized the matrix $P$ as $P=U^{-1}DU$.
Multiply on the left by $U$ to get  $UP=DU$. Now take the $i$th row of both sides
to get $r_i P= d_i r_i$ where $r_i$ is the $i$th row of $U$.
This shows that $r_i$ is a left eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $d_i$ (the 
$i$th entry in the diagonal matrix $D$.)

The argument for the columns of $U$ is similar, starting with $PU^{-1}=U^{-1}D$.

The value  1 is an eigenvalue for $P$ since  $P$ is stochastic, i.e., its 
row sums are all equal to 1. Therefore if you let $v$ be the vector of ones, we have
$P v= 1 v.$

Comment: No problem.${}{}$